# For loop results reverse of expected order

Tags: java, android, loops

The problem is I have a for loop in android , and its seems to be running in the reverse order.

Here is the code :

```
for(i=0;i<strlent;i++)
{
    //ch=st.charAt(i);
//disp(String.valueOf(ch));
disp(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

I have a string and would like to get each characters out of it, but if I feed in "babe" it runs e-b-a-b. I checked the `i` value and it runs as 3-2-1-0. I seriously don't understand why it behaves this way.

This is my disp function

```
public void disp(String st) // this function is used to check with message boxes 
{
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle("Testing");
    adb.setMessage(st);
    adb.show();
}
```

Comment: Maybe your phone is upside down. No seriously though, that can't happen. The problem is in your disp() method or somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe you filled your linked list or array in a wrong order...

Comment: public void disp(String st) // this function is used to check with message boxes 
 {
  AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(this);
  adb.setTitle("Testing");
  adb.setMessage(st);
  adb.show();
  
 }

Comment: That's my disp function , it's simple , this for loop is acting crazy

Comment: Instead posting code in comments add it to your question with [[edit]] option

Comment: the string must have been reversed before this loop, and the commented out code in the loop is the code you want

Comment: @RakeshBk do not post code into the comments edit your post!

Comment: yes i know that the commented code is wat i want , but i wanted to check the integer value , coz it was printing string in reverse order , after commenting i found that i is also printed in reverse order

Comment: @RakeshBk, what if you write your `i` values to log (like `System.out.println()` or `Log.i()`, maybe new alert dialog windows overlaps the old ones so it's just seems to be in reverse order

Comment: it could be the reason , but still , when i tried to manipulate values in a matrix , i had to scratch my hear for a day , coz it was going in reverse order , i don't know y it's acting so , overlapping might not be the reason

Comment: @RakeshBk, add `System.out.println(i);` to your loop and post logcat here, i don't believe you

Comment: @SpongeBobFan you were right :D , it was overlapping !! i concatenated the characters and checked ,it came in proper order , and i ran the loop only once , and it printed 'b' in "babe" , so it means it was overlapping , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Let Me Reverse";

System.out.println("\nIn order..");

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(str.substring(i, i + 1));
}

System.out.println();

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
}

System.out.println();

for(char ch : str.toCharArray()){
    System.out.print(ch);
}

System.out.println("\nIn reverse order..");

for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: the "strlent" variable is the st.length() return value , and ur function will give characters fine , but it will run in reverse order

Comment: What will happen when i==2 for example -> `st.substring(2,1)` what will it return ?

Comment: @RakeshBk Only the last for loop will print in reverse as stated in my answer.

Comment: i reversed the loop , thanks all for your time , i really appreciate it , don't have time to scratch my head over a loop :D , project deadline :D

Comment: @g00dy I saw that and edited.

Comment: @RakeshBk Good luck to your project..

Comment: @RakeshBk - Be sure to Accept the answer which worked for you.

Comment: The thing is it was overlapping guys :D , loop was working correctly before :D

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = "Hello";

for(int i=name.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
     System.out.println(name.charAt(i));
}
```